# Ember, remove wrapping element or change classNames for route

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying come back to `ember.js` after 2 years working with another frameworks. Most annoying "surprise" for me is there no `views` anymore, therefore i cannot customize html elements using something like `classNames` or `tagName`. To be more detailed I'll explain what is my problem relative for:

Lets pretend we have created route, `/myroute` for instance.
Content of our `templates/myroute.hbs` is:

```
<div>test</div>
```

Ok, lets see our html using inspector:

```
<body class="ember-application">
  <div id="ember341" class="ember-view">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'd like to know how i can remove this element `<div id="ember341" class="ember-view">` in a new ember way, how i can change `class` property, tag ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can create a component(they are kinda similar to what views were before) and use `classNames` and `tagName`.

Comment: @JovicaŠuša how can i make component to work with routes ?

Comment: You create a component and just place it inside the route template, components have js and hbs file, in .js file you can set `classNames` and `tagName` and in hbs the template it should render.

Comment: @JovicaŠuša I'd like remove `.ember-view` wrapper for the route, there is no any problems with components itself.

Comment: I think that you can't remove that wrapper because it's needed for Ember to do its work. I wanted to propose to use components inside that template,let's take your example - you could put `<div>test</div>` inside component template and then you can add `classNames` and `tagName` to the component template.

Comment: It was possible when ember had support for `views`. Simple `views/myroute.js` with `tagName: ''` trick. I'm sure, it is possible, but Idk how yet :)

Comment: So just create component like you would view and add whatever you want for `tagName`.

Comment: @JovicaŠuša it does not affect the route, ember creates its wrapper element. I'm trying latest ember from npm, it does not support views anymore, in any way (view or component way)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove `<div id="ember341" class="ember-view">` since Ember uses it to manage the document. **However**, using [components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/defining-a-component/) you are able to do something like this:

**app/components/my-list.js:**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  tag: 'ul',
  classNames: ['foo']
});
```

**app/templates/components/my-list.bhs:**

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
```

---

To use this component, for instance in a route, you could do the following:

```
<p>Here is an awesome list:</p>
{{my-list}}
```

Which would generate the following html:

```
<p>Here is an awesome list:</p>
<ul class="foo">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

---

Here are some useful documentation on how to use components (from the Ember documentation):

- [Defining a Component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/defining-a-component/)
- [The Component Lifecycle](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)
- [Wrapping Content in a Component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/)
- [Customizing a Component's Element](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/)

Comment: it was possible with old `views`.

Answer (score 1):

Not every route does create a `div` but ember creates a single root div that actually cant be modified. This has indeed changed and was possible in previous versions, but now you cant change the class of the root div nor disable it.

However other routes do not create additional `div`s. There is only a single root div you cant modify.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Ember 3.1](https://blog.emberjs.com/2018/02/16/ember-3-1-beta-released.html) you can remove the top level wrapper `div`, with an optional-feature.

**Optional Feature**: Application Template Wrapper

```sh
ember feature:disable application-template-wrapper
```

> Disabling this feature will stop Ember from creating a div around the application. This change may require alterations to your application's CSS, or to any other code that depends upon the presence of the div.

Additionally, enabling this feature will prompt you to optionally run a codemod to add the application div to the application.hbs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me here is a simple way this will remove all ember-view tags

```
export default Route.extend
  render: ->
     $(document).ready ->
       $("body").find(".ember-view").each (i, item)->
         $(item).contents().unwrap();
```

Because we are doing this in render it should be after everything else is complete, but its possible this may break addons and so may be safer to apply this just to the content you wish to change rather than the whole document.

My use case was because we were porting code from rails into ember and so we needed to preserve the same div structure so we could use all our existing scripts and css.